# changing a buttons colour when that button clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a maze where the user enters the dimensions and can then click on a button to change the colour of that button to black. What i eventually want is to be making an ai which will try to navigate the maze the user created with the black rectangle the ai not being allowed to go on.
The problem is i dont know how to change the properties of the button clicked as due to a nested loop being used for creation they all have the same name.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox,Treeview,Scrollbar

class MainMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="entering diemsions", width=300, height=130, bd=5)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=8)
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="creating maze", width=300, height=130, bd=5)
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=8)
        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):
        self.width_lbl = Label(self.frame1, text = "width:")
        self.width_lbl.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)
        self.width_txt = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.width_txt.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.getdimensions_btn = Button(self.frame1, text = "enter dimensions",command = lambda:self.createmaze())
        self.getdimensions_btn.grid(row = 1 , column = 3)

        self.height_lbl = Label(self.frame1, text = "height:")
        self.height_lbl.grid(row = 1 , column = 4)
        self.height_txt = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.height_txt.grid(row = 1, column = 5)

    def createmaze(self):
        width = int(self.width_txt.get())
        height = int(self.height_txt.get())
        for widthcount in range (width):
            for heightcount in range(height):
                self.maze_btn = Button(self.frame2, text = "",width = 4, height = 2)
                self.maze_btn.grid(row = heightcount , column = widthcount)
                self.maze_btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.disablebtn)

    def disablebtn(self,event):
        grid_info = event.widget.grid_info()
        col = grid_info["column"]
        col = int(col)
        row = grid_info["row"]
        row = int(row)


root = Tk()
root.title("hi")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(bg="white")
app = MainMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `event.widget` refers to the widget that was clicked.

Comment: thanks i throught u could just get the info of button clicked my bad, iv just tried 2 ways which both dont work, first self.maze_btn = Button(self.frame2, text = "",width = 4, height = 2, background = "black") does not change the colour, second was  self.maze_btn.config(background = "black") but that just changes the last button that was generated

Comment: never mind fixed it i just forgot to do the grid after making the re making the btn